# Is it possible to customize Salesforce's Social Login Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-community

I'm trying to customize salesforce social login component but I'm not able to find the code. I can find the self registration and and the login form but not the social log-in

Answer (score 0):

You should go through [Social SSO](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/identity_external/identity_external_social) trailhead to understand how the components work together. There are two core components involved - the registration handler (source code generated for you by Salesforce) and the auth provider. Here's an [example](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/InstagramAuthProvider) of the latter for Instagram as the auth source. Salesforce ships a number of auth providers, including a generic auth provider for any OpenID Connect-compliant service.